# Can I Modify What IP Address a Named Host Redirects To?

Tags: apache, dns, reverse-proxy, hosts

I have been rebuilding a new website for my client. At launch, we're going to switch hosting, too, so there will be DNS based changes as well as a completely new website. The Domain Name is staying the same.

I don't have access to the HOSTS file on the current website's machine, so if I do a reverse proxy from the old website to the new website, it won't work because I can't use the HOSTS file to redirect `example.com` to the new IP Address that it's located at.

Is there any way that I can tell Apache what IP to use for a domain name in the configuration of the ProxyPass block?

### Edit

I literally got two lines into writing the `ProxyPass` code when I realized that I couldn't tell the server where `example.com` should go. It seemed like a brick wall and after googling, I realized that I didn't know what I should be searching for because my queries returned nothing useful.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the Host you are proxying to uses name based hosting, and just accessing the website via IP won't work, you can use the `ProxyPreserveHost` option  to send the hostname along with the proxy request to the IP listed in the url.

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.111.2/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.111.2/
    ServerName hostname.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```